# Better circles Interpolation

Tags: sketchup

Is it possible to make the circles finer in Sketchup Web App. I want a 100% circle and no chain of lines.
I use it for 3D-Printing and wonder why the circles look like in former computer games.

[image: Circle Interpolation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first click on the circle tool, look at the VCB which is the text box in the lower right corner.  This box can be used to enter in dimensions and other text options.  When you first click the circle tool, it allows you to enter in the number of sides to use when creating your circle.

The default is 24 which isn't very smooth.  Bumping it to 48 will be fairly visually smooth but if you are using it for 3D printing, you could certainly go much higher.  Your end result will probably depend on the physical size of your 3D printed object.  (I doubt you will need to go above 128 but who knows.)

Answer (score 1):

SketchUp has no true curves or circles, just segmented representations. You can make the segments less noticeable by increasing the number of segments to the cost of file size and performance, but you will never achieve "100% circles".

The segmentation on existing "circles" can be changed from Entity Info (unless they connect to other geometry). For new circles you can type a number into the circle tool and press enter.